# Python mock offline standalone installation

Tags: python, mocking

I need to use python "mock" library for unit testing.

Is it possible to install the library without connecting my development machine to the Internet?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to install "mock" offline. 
Step-by-step guide follows (I use Python 2.7):

1. Download necessary packages provided in .tar.gz archives:
   mock, setuptools, pbr, six, funcsigs
2. Unpack all of the archives
3. Install modules one by one in the following order: setuptools, pbr, six, funcsigs, mock. To install a module, chdir to the folder it was unpacked to and execute      `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

sure... download the source package from PyPI onto a different machine: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock

place it on a usb key, and sneakernet it over to your dev machine.

to install from source package, first uncompress the tarball, then run: `$ python setup.py install`.

Comment: I tried it first. It requires setuptools. I installed setuptools, and ran
`python setup.py install` for mock package.
Then I received "Failed to download" error. 
That's why this very question came into being)

Comment: @Emons yeah.. looks like it has some dependencies... you'd need to also get source packages for those and install them.